# merging several arrays into one if they have the same key inside nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create a function that sorts or filters or map multiple arrays and creates a new one

```
const worker1 =[{day:1, w1:2},{day:2, w1:3},{day:3, w1:1}]
const worker2 =[              {day:2, w2:1},{day:3, w2:2}]
const worker3 =[{day:1, w3:3}              ,{day:2, w3:2}]
```

I have 3 arrays and  i need to write a function that will convert these 3 arrays into one

```
const total=[ {day:1, w1:2, w3:3},
              {day:2, w1:3, w2:1, w3:2},
              {day:3, w1:1, w2:2}  ]
```

Comment: *"if there is no property, we skip it"* What do you mean? A property comprises of a key and value ex, `day: 1`. So do you mean if there's an empty object ? ex `{}`. Also please explain the logic of the first set of arrays becoming the second set of arrays. Also, you need to post the JavaScript that you need to actually work. You give us broken code and we fix it -- we are not supposed to write everything for you. See [ask] and how to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## new solution

```js
const worker1 = [
  { day: 1, w1: 2 },
  { day: 2, w1: 3 },
  { day: 3, w1: 1 },
];
const worker2 = [
  { day: 2, w2: 1 },
  { day: 3, w2: 2 },
];
const worker3 = [
  { day: 1, w3: 3 },
  { day: 2, w3: 2 },
];


console.log(
  sortWorkersByDate(worker1, worker2, worker3)
);
```

```html
<script>
  // with ...obj you can put as many workers you want
  function sortWorkersByDate(...objWorkers) {
    let output = {};

    objWorkers.forEach((worker) => {
      worker.forEach((dayObj) => {
        ({day} = dayObj); // Destructuring assignment https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
        if (!output[day]) output[day] = {};
        // logic for sorting
        Object.assign(output[day], dayObj);
      });
    });

    return output;
  }
</script>
```

basically by:

**using `Object.assign`:**
we first copy the previous day's Object
and then modify the correct key/value **safely** without the fear of deleting all the previous things

> I am 100% sure that the bug is this because if you use `=` equal it deletes the previous and then adds the key/value which is a dangerous move.
>
> more details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign?retiredLocale=it

so if we push `w2`, and previously we have `w1`, it will become `{w1, w2}` (❌ and not `{w2}` as `=` version)

the result will be:

```json
{
  "1": {
    "day": 1,
    "w1": 2,
    "w3": 3
  },
  "2": {
    "day": 2,
    "w1": 3,
    "w2": 1,
    "w3": 2
  },
  "3": {
    "day": 3,
    "w1": 1,
    "w2": 2
  }
}
```

#### want to loop over this array (and you don't how)?

just do

```js
Object
  .values(NAME_OF_OBJECT)
  .forEach();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

---

---

## old answer

```js
const worker1 = [
  { day: 1, w1: 2 },
  { day: 2, w1: 3 },
  { day: 3, w1: 1 },
];
const worker2 = [
  { day: 2, w2: 1 },
  { day: 3, w2: 2 },
];
const worker3 = [
  { day: 1, w3: 3 },
  { day: 2, w3: 2 },
];

console.log(sortWorkersByDay(worker1, worker2, worker3));
```

```html
<script>
  function sortWorkersByDay(...objWorkers) {
    let output = {};

    objWorkers.forEach((worker, workerIndex) => {
      worker.forEach((dayObj) => {
        const dayKey = `day${dayObj.day}`;
        const workerKey = `w${workerIndex + 1}`;

        output[dayKey] = output[dayKey] || {};
        
        // or this Object.assign or it won't work
        Object.assign(output[dayKey], {
          [workerKey]: dayObj[workerKey],
        });
      });
    });

    return output;
  }
</script>
```

the result will be:

```json
{
  "day1": {
    "w1": 2,
    "w3": 3
  },
  "day2": {
    "w1": 3,
    "w2": 1,
    "w3": 2
  },
  "day3": {
    "w1": 1,
    "w2": 2
  }
}
```

Comment: very close, but  **day** must be inside the object, and be one of the properties

Comment: now added a new solution like you said

Comment: @ОлесьДемчук now I find a way to write only 2 lines of code to make it work because of day inside {} (just setting variable if there isn't and Object.assign) so yeah if this helps you please accept the answer. I hope it helped you somehow

Comment: you are my hero